# How to iterate through DataSnapshot from Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data in Firebase:

[image: First Screenshot]

When I try to read all the children of 'hospitals' using `get()`, an `InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>` is being returned:

[image: Second Screenshot]

I need to iterate through the returned value and get all the lat and long of the three children and put it in a `List<Hospitals>`, which has Name, Phone, Lat and Long as its properties, and later plot these coordinates in a `Map`. I am not able to iterate through the `InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>`.

Please help to figure out the iteration?

Code I have tried -

```
fetchMarkers() async {
  nHospitals.clear();
  final snapshot = await dbRef.child('information/hospitals').get();
  if (snapshot.exists) {
    print(snapshot.value);
  }
}
```

I also tried the following, but the same issue: I am not able to iterate through the `InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>`.

```
ref.onValue.listen((event) {
  for (final child in event.snapshot.children) {
    //A list of children is returned
    //print(child);
  }
}, onError: (error) {
  //Handle the error
});
```

This is Hospitals class

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'hospitals.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Hospitals {
  final String lat;
  final String lng;
  final String name;
  final String phone;

  Hospitals(
      {required this.lat,
      required this.lng,
      required this.name,
      required this.phone});

  factory Hospitals.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$HospitalsFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$HospitalsToJson(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a `get()` call is a [`DataSnapshot` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot-class.html), which has a `children` property that has all the child snapshots. That's what you do in the second code snippet, and it looks fine to me.

If you then want to get a child property of that snapshot, you can call `child("lat").value`.

```
ref.get().then((snapshot) {
  for (final hospital in snapshot.children) {
    print(hospital.child("lat").value);
  }
}, onError: (error) {
  ..
});
```

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you so much! What I am trying to achieve is for the entire data to be fetched from the database, iterated through and put in a list of type Hospitals. I was able to iterate last night but I am ending up with a list of lists which looks like this - [[Instance of 'Hospitals'], [Instance of 'Hospitals', Instance of 'Hospitals'], [Instance of 'Hospitals', Instance of 'Hospitals', Instance of 'Hospitals']]. So it is fetching and adding to the list incrementally. How do you suggest I should ideally iterate and put the values in a list of type <Hospitals>? Thank you!

Comment: That looks lke the default `toString` implementation. If you want it to show sometihng else, you might want to override `toString`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/toString.html

Comment: Thank you, Frank. I was able to get the data in the correct mannner.